# React Native : [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native, and this is my first project using React Native that build from scratch. I have a warning issue and the feature i want is not working.

Here are some explanation of what i want :
I have an array of object that i named it as carts, inside the carts it looks like :

```
let carts = [
  {
    merchantId: 1,
    items: [
      {
        productId: 1,
        productQty: 1,
      },
      {
        productId: 2,
        productQty: 5,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    merchantId: 2,
    items: [
      {
        productId: 3,
        productQty: 2,
      },
      {
        productId: 4,
        productQty: 4,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And this is my Screen :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { theme } from '../../../infrastructure/theme';
import SpacerComponent from '../../../components/SpacerComponent';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import MerchantCardComponent from '../components/MerchantCardComponent';
import { tranformCartArray } from '../../../services/carts/CartTransform';

const CartScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [carts, setCarts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const getCarts = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await tranformCartArray();
    setCarts(response);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      getCarts();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  console.log(carts);

  if (carts.length === 0) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.emptyContainter}>
        <Image
          style={styles.imageCart}
          source={require('../../../assets/images/empty_cart.png')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.emptyCartText}>
          Keranjangnya masih kosong nih !
        </Text>
        <SpacerComponent size="xlarge" />
        <Button
          style={styles.buttonExplore}
          mode="contained"
          size={20}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Merchants')}
        >
          <FontAwesome5
            name="shopping-cart"
            size={20}
            color={theme.colors.text.inverse}
          />
          <Text>{'   '}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Eksplor</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.emptyContainter}>
        <ActivityIndicator
          color={theme.colors.ui.primary}
          size={theme.sizes[3]}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {carts.map((merchantAndItems) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Checkout')}>
            <MerchantCardComponent
              merchantAndItems={merchantAndItems}
              key={merchantAndItems.merchantId}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default CartScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  emptyContainter: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.bg.primary,
  },
  imageCart: {
    maxWidth: '90%',
    maxHeight: '45%',
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  emptyCartText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: theme.fonts.regular,
  },
  buttonExplore: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.ui.primary,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
```

I want to pass after transform carts of array to MerchantCardComponent, the type of the transformation I want is the array (carts) become :

```
let carts = [
  {
    merchantId: 1,
    merchantName: 'Merchant A',
    merchantLogo: 'https://assets.backend.com/merchants/1/logo_url.jpg',
    items: [
      {
        productId: 1,
        productName: 'Product One',
        productImage: 'https://assets.backend.com/merchants/1/products/1/product_image.jpg',
        productPrice: 2000,
        productQty: 1,
      },
      {
        productId: 2,
        productName: 'Product Two',
        productImage: 'https://assets.backend.com/merchants/1/products/2/product_image.jpg',
        productPrice: 2000,
        productQty: 5,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    merchantId: 2,
    merchantName: 'Merchant B',
    merchantLogo: 'https://assets.backend.com/merchants/2/logo_url.jpg',
    items: [
      {
        productId: 3,
        productName: 'Product Three',
        productImage: 'https://assets.backend.com/merchants/2/products/3/product_image.jpg',
        productPrice: 2000,
        productQty: 2,
      },
      {
        productId: 4,
        productName: 'Product Four',
        productImage: 'https://assets.backend.com/merchants/4/products/4/product_image.jpg',
        productPrice: 2000,
        productQty: 4,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

So that i can easily just print out the text, without fetch to backend again in the screen. I have make an seperate file for the transform the cart function, here is the code :

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import CartsContext from './CartsContext';

import {
  doRequestMerchantDetail,
  doRequestProductDetail,
} from '../merchants/MerchantsService';

export const tranformCartArray = async () => {
  const [transformCart, setTransformCart] = useState([]);
  const [afterTransform, setAfterTransform] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const { carts } = useContext(CartsContext);

  for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    let [errMerchant, merchant] = await doRequestMerchantDetail(
      carts[i].merchantId,
    );

    for (let j = 0; j < cart[i].items.length; j++) {
      let [errProduct, product] = await doRequestProductDetail(
        carts[i].items[j].productId,
      );
      if (product) {
        setItems(
          ...items,
          ...[
            {
              productName: product.product_name,
              productQty: carts[i].items[j].productQty,
              productPrice: product.product_price,
              productId: carts[i].items[j].productId,
              productImage: product.product_image_url,
            },
          ],
        );
      } else {
        setItems(
          ...items,
          ...[
            {
              productName: 'Error',
              productQty: carts[i].items[j].productQty,
              productPrice: 'Error',
              productId: carts[i].items[j].productId,
              productImage:
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/07/21/12/49/error-6482984_960_720.png',
            },
          ],
        );
      }
    }

    if (merchant) {
      setAfterTransform({
        merchantName: merchant.name,
        merchantLogo: merchant.merchant_logo_url,
        merchantId: carts[i].merchantId,
        items,
      });
    } else {
      setAfterTransform({
        merchantName: 'Error',
        merchantLogo: 'Error',
        merchantId: carts[i].merchantId,
        items,
      });
    }

    setTransformCart(...transformCart, ...[afterTransform]);
  }

  return transformCart;
};
```

Until now i'm still confuse what make the warning show out, and the not working i was mention in the first sentence is the it return an empty array after the transform. Here is the screenshoot of console
[image: ConsoleLog in Screen]

Comment: `tranformCartArray` isn't a react component or custom React hook so you can't use the `useState` and `useContext` hooks there. You may be able to convert it into a custom hook, but I'm a bit thrown by the last line `setTransformCart(...tranformCartArray, ...[afterTransform]);` which seems to attempt to spread a reference to the function itself. Or perhaps you meant `setTransformCart(... transformCart, ...[afterTransform]);`.

Comment: @DrewReese so may i ask what is the best way to solve this problem ? Thanks !

Comment: yes what i mean is  `setTransformCart(...transformCart, ...[afterTransform]);`. Thanks for the correction !

Comment: Think you could walk us through the logic in `tranformCartArray` callback. I'm trying to follow the logic and it seems like with some of the state updates you'll be updating from stale state that hasn't updated yet. Was this logic that was previously working elsewhere or is it just something you coded up and it hasn't actually worked yet? I'm working through a solution and want to ensure I don't steer you wrong.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, i just coded up and it hasnt worked yet. The logic in `transformCartArray` is just replace the old array with the new array after fetch the detail from backend API.

Comment: Oh, I see now, so you basically still just need a utility function that augments the existing data in the `carts` state from the context, to store locally in the `CartScreen` component, is this correct?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, that is i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tranformCartArray` isn't a react component or custom React hook so you can't use the `useState` and `useContext` hooks.

Additionally, the "unhandled rejection" was thrown because the `getCarts` function is declared `async` so it implicitly returns a Promise and when the React hooks error was thrown there was no `catch` block or `.catch` of a Promise chain to catch and handle it.

I would suggest passing the `carts` state from the context into the `tranformCartArray` utility function, and return an augmented carts array. This allows you to remove any and all hooks from the function.

```
export const tranformCartArray = async (carts) => {
  const newCarts = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    let [, merchant] = await doRequestMerchantDetail(
      carts[i].merchantId,
    );
    
    const newItems = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < carts[i].items.length; j++) {
      let [, product] = await doRequestProductDetail(
        carts[i].items[j].productId,
      );

      newItems.push({
        productName: product?.product_name ?? 'Error',
        productQty: carts[i].items[j].productQty,
        productPrice: product?.product_price ?? 'Error',
        productId: carts[i].items[j].productId,
        productImage: carts[i].items[j].product_image_url,
      });
    }
    
    newCarts.push({
      merchantName: merchant?.name ?? 'Error',
      merchantLogo: merchant?.merchant_logo_url ?? 'Error',
      merchantId: carts[i].merchantId,
      items: newItems,
    });
  }

  return newCarts;
};
```

CartScreen

```
const CartScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [carts, setCarts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const { carts: contextCarts } = useContext(CartsContext); // <-- access context

  const getCarts = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await tranformCartArray(contextCarts); // <-- pass context carts value
      setCarts(response);
    } catch(error) {
      // handle any errors?
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, now everything is working well !